# Chrome Storage Sync get items in a persistent order

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, soundcloud

I'm working in a Chrome extension that stores a temporary playlist from items in SoundCloud to perform several actions on it later.
So... I know Chrome Storage is an object and "can´t" be ordered *per se*, but I really need that order in any feasible way.

I tried storing objects in an Array and then Storing that Array in Storage after pushing a new element at the end of it and was the perfect workaround until, with 27 objects in it, Chrome told me that I had reached memory limit (I'm going to need more elements to store.)
Storing each element as separate objects allows me virtually any amount of them (I think 50mb, which is enough for sure), but get method throws elements the way it wants (obviously, being an object).
Objects are stored with timestamp keys, but still not working at all.

Is there a "light way" to do so?
Code is not definitive and I'm thinking in appending elements directly to a new window, leaving storage calls for other stuff and move to "lighter" code, but would like first to know if this is somehow possible.

**CODE** - popup.js (here is where order is not persistent)

```
function appendTracks(){

    chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function (storageObject) {

//TODO check if is song
            $.each( storageObject, function( key, trackData ) {

              trackContainer(trackData["permalink"]);

            });

        });
}
function trackContainer(trackPermalink){
  console.log(trackPermalink);
  var trackWidget;
  $.getJSON(
  'http://soundcloud.com/oembed' +
  '?format=json' + 
  '&url='+trackPermalink+'&visual=false'
).done(function (embedData) { 
  trackWidget = embedData.html;
  $("#mainPlayList").append(trackWidget);
});
console.log(trackWidget);
return trackWidget;
}
```

**CODE** - main.js (Storage Setter with timestamp as key)

```
function downloadClick(a) {
    playListName = "";
    var b = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: a.data.reqUrl
    }).done(function(a) {

        var time = Date.now();
        var timeStamp = Math.round(time/1000);

        var key = timeStamp.toString()+"queueSc";

        var trackData = {
            "trackId" : a["id"],
            "trackTitle" : a["title"],
            "thumbnail" : a["artwork_url"],
            "streamUrl" : a["stream_url"],
            "permalink" : a["permalink_url"],
            "duration" : a["duration"],
            "genre" : a["genre"]};

        trackData[key] = "key";

        getStorage(null,function(storageObject){

            if(!isTrackInList(trackData,storageObject)){

            setStorage({
                    [key]: trackData 
            });

            }else{

                 console.log("ya esta en la lista"); 

            }

            });       
        
    })
}

function isTrackInList(trackData, storageObject){

    var isInList = false;
    $.each( storageObject, function( key, value ) {

        if(trackData["trackId"] == value["trackId"]){
            isInList = true;
        } 
    });

    return isInList;

}
```

I think is important to say that other than the order issue there is not any problem with it, everything runs fine, although there are things that could be more "elegant" for sure.
Thanks in advance, hope you can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are exceeding the `QUOTA_BYTES_PER_ITEM`, i.e. the storage limit you are allowed per object. If you use `chrome.storage.sync` you are limited to `8,192 Bytes`. Using `chrome.storage.local` will allow you to store unlimited size per item.

**Note** using `chrome.storage.local` makes your data local to that machine and thus not synced across browsers on different machine.

Comment: So, if back to storing objects to array but with local storage would work? I know I was exceding QUOTA_BYTES at that moment, but only for size per object, not for storage size, I think size per object limit will be the same with local. Correct me if I´m wrong

Comment: it should work using `chrome.storage.local` but don't forget to add the `unlimitedStorage` permission into your manifest if you want unlimited storage size.

Comment: I´ve checked extension docs and no limit per item is explicitly set for local, and it does for sync, i´m going to assume there is not one. Going to try with this and come back with results (unlimited storage is declared although I have had no need for it till lnow). Thanks!!

Comment: Yeah you are right, I was writing my correction to the answer I gave. I've only used local storage so I've never run into the same problem as you. I believe it still should solve your problem. If you would like to use `chrome.storage.sync` please let me know so that I can come up with another solution.

Comment: If local works for this I think there will be no problem storing that data maybe reparsing to save it in sync to use it when needed, sync is just an extra feature to me for this, but could think in a way to store that data in sync in other way if needed.

Comment: Just to note, you can go back to your initial array implementation because local storage should overcome the limit per item you previously had. Thus also keeping your items ordered.

Comment: Got it, with local solution no limit is exceded, so Thanks!! I´ve also managed to keep code shrunk to the minimum, so the only data stored is no more objects but strings, temporary code posted

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [EyuelDK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1593024/eyueldk) and finally an async call has been needed, I will try to solve this the next.

**CODE** - popup.js

```
function appendTracks(){

    chrome.storage.local.get("souncloudQueue", function (storageObject) {

            var length = storageObject["souncloudQueue"].length;

            for (var i=0;i<length;i++){

              var trackPermalink = storageObject["souncloudQueue"][i];

              console.log(i, trackPermalink);

              $("#mainPlayList").append(trackContainer(trackPermalink));

            }

        });
}

function trackContainer(trackPermalink){
  console.log(trackPermalink);
  var trackWidget;

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://soundcloud.com/oembed' +
    '?format=json' + 
    '&url='+trackPermalink,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
      trackWidget = data.html;
    }
});
console.log(trackWidget);
return trackWidget;

}
```

**CODE** - main.js

```
function downloadClick(a) {

var trackUrl = a.data.reqUrl;

console.log(trackUrl);

getStorage("souncloudQueue", function(callback){

    console.log(callback["souncloudQueue"]);

    var tempArray = callback["souncloudQueue"];

    tempArray.push(trackUrl);

    setStorage({"souncloudQueue": tempArray}, function() {

    });

})
```

}